# iframe resizing when content is smaller than default size (300x150)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

In my current scenario I have a page loading an iframe. The content of the iframe cannot be determined beforehand therefore I need to dynamically adjust the size using javascript. The code I use to accomplish this is the following:

```
newIframe.onload = function() {
    var cw = newIframe.contentWindow;
    var doc = cw.document;
    var body = doc.body,
        html = doc.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);

    var width = Math.max(body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth,
        html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth);

    newIframe.style.width = width + "px";
    newIframe.style.height = height + "px";
}
```

Everything works as expected except when the content of the iframe is smaller than width=300 or height=150. When this is the case (e.g. the iframe contains only an image w:160 and h:600) the computed width is wrong.

Comment: What is the iframe's initial value? (in code or css) ... and please add the html/css in question.

Comment: I also guess that the iframe's inital value is wider than the image you referenced, and as the its width doesn't shrink if content does, you can't measure on the body as it reflects the iframe's width when content is less wide. You need to measure on the body's children elements if the body has the same init value as the iframe has.

Comment: @LGSon I can't set an initial value to the iframe since the content is dynamic. It can be 160px as well as 300px... you can try it here [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaJOqR)

Comment: I get that, but what is the value of the iframe's width before you add any content to it? ... That value is the value you will get when you compute the iframe contents body if the content is smaller than that very same iframe width and that is also why your computed values does not work when content is smaller

Comment: I think this will fix it, change the iframe initial values from `width: auto; height: auto;` to `width: 0; height: 0;`

Comment: @LGSon I just wrote the same exact code! Ahah! Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

By setting the initial width and height of the iframe to `0` the issue is gone because those values will be used as defaults.