# Canvas in basic HTML page always sized as 300x150.

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have simplified my issue to a basic HTML document with a `<canvas>` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
      body {
        border: 1px solid #ff5500;
        background-color: black;
      }
      canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
 <canvas id="canv" style='width:1024px;height:768px'>
  </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

But however I set  the `width` and `height` (using pixels, percentages or viewport units), whether or not I set the style (e.g. `style='width:1024px;height:768px'`), and however I resize the browser window, the dev console always reports width x height as 300x150.   Why is this, and how do I deal with it?

Here's the output from the dev console:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canv");
undefined
c.style.width
"1024px"
c.style.height
"768px"
c.width
300
c.height
150
```

The same behaviour occurs in both Chromium and Firefox.

I have trawled Stack Overflow and the web in general and found much on the difference between `width` and `clientWidth`, and a similar question regarding Fabric.js, but no answer to this specific question.

Comment: You have to set it in JS too. canv.width = ***

Comment: You should try to use the width and heigth attributes directly on the canvas tag: `<canvas id="canv" width="1024" height="768">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the width and height that you are referring to-- are **html attributes** and not css.

They can be modified like this;

```html
<canvas width="1024" height="768" style="border:1px solid black;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to solve the issue.   The comment from @Thomas To. also, which gave the same suggestion.   But I'm still puzzled as to why the defaults seem to be `width="300" height="150"`, though this doesn't really matter.

Comment: @teraspora [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868255/iframe-resizing-when-content-is-smaller-than-default-size-300x150) and [`<svg>`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/23181) [2](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27376496) also share this `300x150px` default size, this might be related to CSS [`intrinsic-size`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#intrinsic-sizes) > This case was previous calculated from a 300x150 default size, rather than the box’s min size. This is believed to be a better behavior, and likely to be Web-compatible

Answer (score 4):

You have to change canv.width or .height in JS or set the attribute in HTML directly. Without any CSS or JS needed.

Example:

```js
var can = document.querySelector("#testC");
var can2 = document.querySelector("#testC2");

console.log("Canvas before JS: ", can.width, "x", can.height);
console.log("Canvas in HMTL: ", can2.width, "x", can2.height);

can.width = 600;
can.height = 600;

console.log("Canvas after JS: ", can.width, "x", can.height);
console.log("Canvas in HMTL: ", can2.width, "x", can2.height);
```

```html
<canvas id="testC" width="300" height="300">
<canvas id="testC2" width="600" height="600">
```

This will log:

```
Canvas before JS: 300x300
Canvas in HMTL: 600x600
Canvas after JS: 600x600
Canvas in HMTL: 600x600
```